# Spring expression language (SpEL) in a console

Tags: spring, spring-el

Is there something somewhere with a swing console with a shell for Spring Expression Language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the code in `org.springframework.expression` submodule tests you can build a swing client that evaluates the SpEL statements and provides the desired results

Comment: OK, I have write something I like. The two answers are same, so I give answer point to the rajendra, and "useful" point to opyate :-) THANKS !

Answer (score 1):

There's no console or command-line evaluator to my knowledge, but I suggest you download the code for the `org.springframework.expression` submodule and have a look at the tests. You can modify those and try various expressions.

**UPDATE**

If this looks similar to the winning answer, have a look at the timestamp ;-)

Comment: Thanks, but it's to include in an application, with end users, it's not to learn or try.

Comment: Heu... yes with your update ! I'm confusing absolutly and totaly. Planty of sorry.